# ValueError when assigning array in Python

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, sumo

**Description:**
https://github.com/Maunish-dave/Dynamic-Traffic-light-management-system this is the repo I used.
I'm working on a Sumo simulation project using Python. I have download are MAP from OSM web wizard.I was trying to optimize the traffic using reinforcement learning.when I try to train the model I encountered a ValueError when assigning an array in the `store_transition` method. The error occurs on line 131, and the specific message is "could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (4,)."

```py
# Relevant code snippet causing the error
def store_transition(self, state, state_, action, reward, done, junction):
    index = self.memory[junction]["mem_cntr"] % self.max_mem
    self.memory[junction]["state_memory"][index] = state
    self.memory[junction]["new_state_memory"][index, :] = state_


I want to know what is this shape is why it's causeing the error when i try to load the model how to fix this
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example